# Как присвоить константной переменной значение после условия

Tags: c++

Мне нужно написать функцию которая принимает в качестве аргумента значение `value`. В начале в функции должно быть обьявление константной переменной `const int` далее исходя из значения `value` присвоить ей нужное значение

```
void func(int value)
{
    const int a;
    if(value == 1)
    {
        a = 10;
    }
    if(value == 2)
    {
        a = 20;
    }

}

int main()
{
    func(2);
}
```

При таком коде у меня ошибка которая заключаеться в необходимости инициализации.
Можно ли как-то сделать присваивание константной переменной в условии

Comment: Это похоже на проблему XY - значение констант задается только при инициализации и затем не меняется. Поясните, почему вы вдруг принялись пытаться присвоить какое-то новое значение после инициализации и как вы потом намереваетесь использовать его.

Comment: Ну просто определите как  `const int a {value * 10};`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вообще, так делать нельзя. Но если задание звучит **именно так**, то можно (лучше так не делать) так:

```cpp
void func(int value)
{
    const int volatile a = 0;
    int *p = const_cast<int*>(&a);
    if(value == 1)
    {
        *p = 10;
    }
    if(value == 2)
    {
        *p = 20;
    }
    cout << "New a: " << a << '\n';
}
```

Или можно использовать тернарный оператор:

```cpp
void func(int value)
{
    const int a = (value == 1) ? 10 : ((value == 2) ? 20 : -1);
    cout << "A: " << a << '\n';
}
```

Comment: первый пример кода прям пример как не нужно никогда делать

Comment: @KoVadim я предупредил, что так лучше не делать. Там пусть автор сам думает и решает.

Answer (score 2):

Для сложной инициализации констант можно использовать вот такой способ через лямбду, которая тут же вызывается - IIFE

```
void func(int value)
{
    const int a = [value]() {
        if(value == 1)
        {
            return 10;
        }
        if(value == 2)
        {
            return 20;
        }
        return 100;
    }();
}
```

Такой синтаксис позволяет делать практически любые вычисления.

Comment: Но можно использовать не только лямбду, но и просто функцию (в т.ч. inline)

Comment: да там тысячи способов. Но может допфункцию нельзя

Comment: Будем надеяться, что чем больше ТС узнает способов, тем проще ему дальше будет.

Comment: и сюда снова минусатор подъехал. когда уже они научатся хотя бы комментировать свои несогласия

Answer (score 1):

Еще два варианта(тернарная операция и определение по конкретной формуле):

```
void func(int value)
{
    const int a = (value == 1) ? 10 : (value == 2) ? 20 : (value == 3) ? 60 : 100;
    //...
}
```

или

```
void func(int value)
{
    const int a = value * 10;
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто сначала вычисляете, а потом инициализируете:

```
void func(int value)
{
    int b;
    if(value == 1)
    {
        b = 10;
    }
    if(value == 2)
    {
        b = 20;
    }

    const int a = b;

}
```

Кстати, а что вы будете делать, если `value` равно, скажем, 0?