# Почему при обьявлении константной переменной с помощью тернарного оператора не удаёться создать двумерный массив

Tags: c++

Мне нужно создать двумерный массив размер которого определиться в ходе условия что-то вроде

```
void func(value)
{
    const char size = (value == 1) ? 10 : (value == 2) ? 20 : 0;
    int m[size][4] = {};
}
```

Но возникает ошибка `выражение должно иметь константное значение`
в чем проблема если `size` константа?

Comment: Не просто константой, а известной во время компиляции. А значение value - не известно.

Comment: Все эти подробности надо было указывать в оригинальном вопросе, а то там получилось 4 неправильных ответа https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1251337/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8f .

Comment: вот вот. то есть, это все таки была проблема XY. Теперь ждем следующий вопрос, где нам расскажут, где именно берется значение value (думаю, от генератора случайных чисел)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

size это константа, но 'value' которая участвует в вычислениях не является константой. Значение константной size станет известно только после вычислений которые вы задали. Размер **статического** массива должен быть известен на этапе компиляции. Я сейчас нашел несколько способов решения этой задачки:

1)

```
void func()
{
    const int value = 1;   //Вместо 1 можно поставить любое константное число
    const char size = (value == 1) ? 10 : (value == 2) ? 20 : 0;
    int m[size][4] = {};
}
```

Но тогда в этих вычислениях не будет смысла. Даже если вы укажете const в параметре функции это все равно не поможет

```
void func(const int value)
{
    ...
}
```

так как мы все равно можем передать в функцию разные значения 'value' во время **выполнения** программы, а раз это так, то и размер массива будет известен только во время **выполнения** программы, а так как это статический массив его размер должен быть известен уже на этапе компиляции.

2. Динамически выделить массив и не забыть освободить память.

```
void func(int value)
{
    const char size = (value == 1) ? 10 : (value == 2) ? 20 : 0;
    int** m = new int*[size];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        m[i] = new int[4];
    }

    //Освобождаем память
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        delete[] m[i];
    }
    delete[] m;
    m = nullptr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

При определении массива простого `const` в общем-то недостаточно: `const` - это просто обещание не менять полученное *при инициализации* значение. А нужен `constexpr` - т.е. это значение известно при компиляции, а не в момент инициализации.